# How to load $mft by UltraEdit?

Tags: windows-8, permissions, administrator

I'm the administrator of my OS(Win8), and have ownership and full control permission to all files in C drive. Besides I have turned off the LUA.

However, when I tended to open `C:\$mft` by UE I got a refutative message said that I didn't have enough authority...

Why? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Not being able to access the $mft is not a problem. You can't access your own brain stem, either. 

See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntfs which states:

$MFT "Describes all files on the volume, including file names, timestamps, stream names, and lists of cluster numbers where data streams reside, indexes, security identifiers, and file attributes like "read only", "compressed", "encrypted", etc."

Answer (score 1):

$MFT is part of the (NTFS) the file system. You're not the file system, so you don't have permission to it.  :)

Perhaps try editing it from another OS (like a Linux LiveCD, or a WinPE disk), even though that would probably be a bad idea, and could lead to an unreadable disk.

[Related forum topic](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=324) about accessing it. It has some good info about the driver blocking access.